# can pcall return value of called function instead of boolean result true/false?

Tags: lua

Can pcall return value of called function instead of boolean result true/false?

for example

```
function f()
return 'some text'
end

print(tostring(pcall(f)))
```

print will show only true or false instead of value returned by f

Comment: Drop the `tostring`. You are truncating the pcall return to a single value. pcall returns `bool, <values from function`. See [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

tostring selects only first parameter.

```
a,b = pcall(f)
print(b) --> 'some text'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function f()
  return 'some text'
end

local status, res = pcall(f)
```

if *pcall*() succeeded, *status* is true and *res* is the return value of *f*().
if *pcall*() failed, *status* is false and *res* is the error message.